# Spacy_DLL load failed while importing nn_parser

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, pipeline, spacy, french

I am trying to download the french module for Spacy with the command python -m spacy download fr_core_news_md , but it get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 143, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing nn_parser: The specified module could not be found.
```

How to fix it?

Python 3.8.2 (64 bit) on Windows 10*64

Thank you!

Comment: I am getting this error too.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this error by installing Visual C++ redist on my Windows machine.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to fix this by installing the MS VC redist package. If you use, chocolately: https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist140

```
choco install vcredist140
```